# What is the difference between assigning an empty array and using SetLength(arr, 0)?

Tags: delphi

When emptying an array, is there any difference that one should be aware of between the following alternatives?

Assuming `arr` is a `TArray<string>`:

```
  SetLength(arr, 0);
```

or

```
  arr := [];
```

I'm *guessing* they are the same, but my Delphi is a bit rusty and I seem to recall subtle "peculiarities" coming back to haunt me after months of seemingly working code before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `arr` is a dynamic array variable, then

```
SetLength(arr, 0)
```

and

```
arr := nil
```

and the new (Delphi XE7+)

```
arr := []
```

are all equivalent.

The key to understand this equivalence is the following part from the [`SetLength`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) documentation:

> Following a call to `SetLength`, `S` is guaranteed to reference a unique string or array -- that is, a string or array with a reference count of one.

Also, recall that an empty dynamic array is [represented](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types) by a `nil` pointer, and not a pointer to a "length-zero dynamic array heap object":

> When the variable is empty (uninitialized) or holds a zero-length array, the pointer is `nil` and no dynamic memory is associated with the variable.

Comment: You missed `Finalize(arr)`